# Adding times not working but subtracting works- Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am using `datetime` module for adding and subtracting times, I'm using the code below for reducing the time in seconds

```
from datetime import datetime
h1='05:00:01'
h2='00:00:01'
format='%H:%M:%S'
newtime=datetime.strptime(h1,format)-datetime.strptime(h2,format)
print(newtime)
```

This gives me

```
5:00:00
```

But when I add the times together, it gives me an error:

```
from datetime import datetime
h1='05:00:01'
h2='00:00:01'
format='%H:%M:%S'
newtime=datetime.strptime(h1,format)+datetime.strptime(h2,format)
print(newtime)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

How can I add 2 different times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
h1='05:00:01'
h2='00:00:01'
format='%H:%M:%S'
h1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(h1,format)
h2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(h2,format)
newtime = h1 + datetime.timedelta(hours=h2.hour, minutes=h2.minute, seconds=h2.second) 

print(newtime.strftime(format))
```

**Output:**

```
05:00:02
```

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` is not a time, it's a date and time - an answer to "when", not to "how long". By leaving off the date part, you got January 1st, 1900. Dates subtract (difference of two datetimes is the elapsed duration); but what would be a sum of two dates?

What you wanted to do is not add two datetimes, but two durations, as represented by Python's `datetime.timedelta` class. Durations can, unsurprisingly, both add and subtract.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using `datetime` only like:

```
from datetime import datetime

h1= datetime.strptime('05:00:01', '%H:%M:%S')
h2= datetime.strptime('00:00:01', '%H:%M:%S')

print((h1 - datetime.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S') + h2).time())
# 05:00:02
```